# Latest cloud images does not seem to be available on AWS

Tags: cloud, amazon-ec2

The latest Trusty cloud images published at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/ do not appear to be available on AWS. We normally use this link to locate the latest successful nighly build. Can someone clarify the reason for the same?

The AMI query link (http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) points to a 2 week old image.

Thanks
Krishnan